# How can I attach large files by passing Outlook’s attachment size limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365, office-js, attachment

``const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
const maxSize = 41;

```
    const truncateFile = async (file, maxSize) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                const text = event.target.result;
                const truncatedText = text.substring(0, maxSize);
                const truncatedBlob = new Blob([truncatedText], { type: file.type });
                const truncatedFile = new File([truncatedBlob], file.name, { type: file.type });
                resolve(truncatedFile);
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    };

    const modifiedFile = new File([selectedFile], selectedFile.name + '.attach', { type: selectedFile.type });
    console.log(modifiedFile.name);
    const newmodifiedFile = await truncateFile(modifiedFile, maxSize);
    setUploadFileName(newmodifiedFile.name);
    setFileNames((prevFileNames) => [...prevFileNames, newmodifiedFile.name]);
    simulateFileUpload(newmodifiedFile);
    setIsUploading(true);

    if (newmodifiedFile) {
        const base64 = await convertFileToBase64(newmodifiedFile);
        console.log(base64);
        const fileName = newmodifiedFile.name;

        handleUploadFile(base64, fileName);
        getAttachmentIds();
    }
};
console.log(fileNames);

const handleUploadFile = (base64, fileName) => {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async(
        base64, fileName, { isInline: false },
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.error("Failed to add attachment: ", result.error);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In the context of React.js, I initially managed to modify the file size to precisely 41 bytes, aligning with the specific requirements. However, the ultimate goal remains to preserve the file's original size upon upload. This approach ensures that the file retains its complete content and functionality within the application, maintaining its integrity and intended behavior.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZIq.png)``

Comment: Really unclear what you are talking about here. What do "large" files, and a tiny text file of only 41 bytes in size, have to do with each other? Outlook's mail attachment size limits can hardly be in the couple-dozen-of-bytes range, I suppose?

Comment: Large file means 500MB file or 1GB file.

Comment: Then what is _"I initially managed to modify the file size to precisely 41 bytes, aligning with the specific requirements"_ supposed to mean?

Comment: You shouldn't send 1gb files over an email. Just host them on a separate cloud service and send a link to the file instead.

Comment: Could  you describe your use case a bit more as the receiving system may not allow large files - so is this a specific scenario rather than a general one?